# React setstate with a json value

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using a jquery datatable.net in my react application. Everything normally works fine but when i am fetching a record from the api and setting that with a setState its not saving the record.

this is my useState and arrow function

```
const[state, setstate] = useState({
        datacustomer : []
    })
    


    // get customer details
    const _doGetcustomer = () =>{

        var api_token=localStorage.getItem("authtoken");
        const params = JSON.stringify({
            api_token: api_token
        });
   
        axios.post(Config.API_CUSTOMER_LIST,params,
            { 
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                },
            })
      .then(function (response) {
        var responsedata=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
       // setdatacustomer(responsedata.data);
       setstate({
           ...state,
           datacustomer : responsedata.data
       })
        
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
        // always executed
        });
    }
```

This is my useEffect to call function and incorporate with the jquery datatable.

```
useEffect(() =>{

   _doGetcustomer();

   console.log(state.datacustomer);
    $(function() {
        var table = $('#kt_datatable');

        
        table.DataTable({
            data: state.datacustomer,
            columns: [
                { data: 'customer_name'},
                { data: 'customer_address'},
                { data: 'customer_company'},
                { data: 'customer_state'},
                { data: 'customer_postal'},
                { data: 'customer_country'},
                { data: 'customer_email'},
            ]
        });
    });

}, []);
```

I am using a back end laravel with a datatable extension. That creates json structure like this below

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":4,"recordsFiltered":4,"data":[{"customer_id":2,"customer_name":"s","customer_address":"ssssssssssssss","customer_company":"sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss","customer_state":"ssssssssssssssssssssss","customer_postal":"ssssssssssssssssssss","customer_country":"Afganistan","customer_email":"sjsjjs@jsjsj.com"},{"customer_id":3,"customer_name":"sss","customer_address":"sssssssssssssssss","customer_company":"ssssssssssssssssssssssss","customer_state":"sssssssssssssssssss","customer_postal":"ssssssssssss","customer_country":"Afganistan","customer_email":"sjsjjs@jsjsj.com"},{"customer_id":4,"customer_name":"Saju","customer_address":"weston street","customer_company":"wontonee","customer_state":"delhi","customer_postal":"110058","customer_country":"India","customer_email":"james@james.com"},{"customer_id":5,"customer_name":"Saju Gopal","customer_address":"janak puri","customer_company":"Wontonee","customer_state":"new delhi","customer_postal":"110058","customer_country":"India","customer_email":"james@james.com"}],"input":[]}
```

Comment: make sure that `response` is in correct format.

Comment: Response is in this  format :) here is the screen shot https://prnt.sc/1979hu6

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will work actually if we fetch a data and integrate it in the jquery datatable in react. Because setState we can iterate and open up in rendering like this. But this will also populate the datatable but different way.

```
{items.map(item => (
        <tr>
            <td>{item.customer_name}</td>
            <td>{item.customer_name}</td>
            <td>{item.customer_name}</td>
            <td>{item.customer_name}</td>
            <td>{item.customer_name}</td>
        </tr>
        ))}
```

We can normally use jquery datatable in react if its data set is declare in a code.

so i change my code to call ajax inside the use effect and populate the record. But if any body want to use a datatable i would recommend to use React datatable or table. Header i am using to check the auth user.

```
useEffect(() =>{
        var api_token=localStorage.getItem("authtoken");
        const params = JSON.stringify({
            api_token: api_token
        });

    $(function() {
        var table = $('#kt_datatable');
        var api_token=localStorage.getItem("authtoken");
       // const params = JSON.stringify({
         //   api_token: api_token
       // });
       

       table.DataTable({
           // data: dataSet,
            processing: true,
           // serverSide: true,
             ajax: {
                 url : Config.API_CUSTOMER_LIST,
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 type: "POST",
                 data: function () {
                    return JSON.stringify({api_token: localStorage.getItem("authtoken")  });
                  }
             },
            responsive: true,
            columns: [
                { data: 'customer_name'},
                { data: 'customer_address'},
                { data: 'customer_company'},
                { data: 'customer_country'},
                { data: 'customer_email'},
            ]
        });
    });

}, []);
```